# How long does a UDP packet keeps floating and where?

Tags: sockets, routes, udp

We keep hearing about unreliability of udp that it may reach or not reach or just reach out of order (Signifying delay).

Where is it held until delivered?

Since its connection less if you keep sending packets without a network connection where will it go? Driver buffer?

Similarly when the receiver is not reachable is the packet immediately lost or does it float around a bit expecting host to be available soon? if yes then where?

Comment: this might help https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt

Answer (score 0):

On a direct connection from one device to another, with no intervening devices, there shouldn't be a problem. Where you can run into problems is where you go through a bunch of switches and routers (like the Internet).

A few reasons:

- If a switch drops a frame, there is no mechanism to resend the frame.
- Routers will buffer packets when they get congested, and packets can
  be dropped if the buffers are full, or they may be purposely dropped to prevent congestion.
- Load balancing can cause packets to be delivered out of order.

You have no control over anything outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is it held until delivered?

Packet buffering can occur if packets arrive faster than the device can read. Buffering can be either at NIC of the device or  software queue of device driver or in the software queue between driver and stack. But, if the rate of arrival 
is much higher such that it cannot be handled by these buffering mechanisms, then it will get dropped at those appropriate layer/location (based on design).

> Since its connection less if you keep sending packets without a
>   network connection where will it go? Driver buffer?

If there is no network, there might be no other intermediate network devices and hence there should not be significant problems. But, it also depends on your architecture / design / configurations. If the configured value of internal OS receive buffer limit / socket buffer size (SO_RCVBUF, rmem_max, rmem_default) is exceeded, there can be drops here. And, if the software queue in respective device driver overflows or the software queue between device driver & stack of the device overflows, there can be drops here. Also, if the CPU is busy addressing another priority task where by it suspends reception, there can be drops here.

> Similarly when the receiver is not reachable is the packet immediately
>   lost or does it float around a bit expecting host to be available
>   soon? if yes then where?

If there is no reachable destination, it shall be dropped by router. 
Also, note that the particular router shall also drop the packet if the TTL/hoplimit count (in IP) is  zero by the time the packet reaches this router.